Short film about a man trapped in Telephone Box
When I was very young in the mid 80's, I can remember watching a short film about a man that got trapped in a classic Red phone box. This was possibly filmed in London. After getting stuck, various attempts were made by various members of the public and possibly police, fire service to free the man. After these attempts failed, the phone box containing the man was loaded on to a truck and then taken somewhere where dozens more of these phone boxes (containing other people) were basically just left as if there was no hope, and nothing more could be done.
Anyone know the title for this? Also be good to know who wrote the script, and what other work they did. 
Although I remember watching this in the 80's, it could have been made before then.

Sound like 1972's Spanish made for television film La cabina.

In the 35-minute film, a man becomes trapped in a telephone booth, while passersby seem unable to help him.

Wikipedia synonyms matched with all your provided details with similar ending. Here is the trailer for the same :




Ahh.. you beat me by seconds.

Could have sworn it was a UK based film..... i guess that's what 30 years does to your memory! Phonebox was red at least!

One of my all-time favourite movies. You spend the entire time just thinking ..whut?? Totally surreal, set in a mundane surrounding.
